# Jsoup to parse multiple websites for links published today

Tags: web-scraping, jsoup

I am currently using jsoup (below) to output a .csv of links which include a string date format in the url from just one website.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;

public class readAllLinks {

    public static Set<String> uniqueURL = new HashSet<String>();
    public static String my_site;
    public static String published = ("20180731");

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        readAllLinks obj = new readAllLinks();
        my_site = ("news24.com/SouthAfrica/News");
        obj.get_links("https://www.news24.com/SouthAfrica/News/");
    }

    private void get_links(String url) {
        try {
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
            Elements links = doc.select("a");

            FileOutputStream fout=new FileOutputStream("links.csv");  
            PrintStream csv=new PrintStream(fout);  
            links.stream().map((link) -> link.attr("abs:href")).forEachOrdered((this_url) -> {
                boolean add = uniqueURL.add(this_url);
                if (add && this_url.contains(my_site) && this_url.contains(published)) {
                    System.out.println(this_url);
                    get_links(this_url);
                    }

                if (this_url.contains(published))
                    csv.println(this_url);
            } );    

        } catch (IOException ex) {

        }

    }
}
```

Instead I would like to make a csv of links published today (i.e using today's date) from multiple websites.

How do you specify the .select for the newly published links to get the date contained in a span?

And how do you parse multiple websites from a list?

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This will select all links that contains value of variable 'published'.

```
Elements links = doc.select("a[href*="+published+"]");
```

Comment: Or you can use this selector: doc.select(#divContainer:has(#divPublishedDate:contains("2018-08-02")) > a);